Can you use a RawRectangleF that extends into the negative areas of the render target when drawing a bitmap in SharpDX Direct 2D?
I've been messing around with Direct 2D in WPF recently and I've been attempting to create a way to view DXF files using Direct2D via Sharp DX. I found that panning the render target is quite slow on larger DXF files so I've been attempting to handle panning using a bitmap. So far, this works well enough as long as the DXF file remains in positive territory. I am using this method to load/re-load the bitmap when the program starts or when the window changes size:
        private void LoadBitmap(RenderTarget target)
        {
            if (LayerManager is null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (bitmapRenderTarget is not null)
            {
                bitmapRenderTarget.Dispose();
                bitmapRenderTarget = null;
            }
            bitmapRenderTarget = new BitmapRenderTarget(target, CompatibleRenderTargetOptions.None, new Size2F((float)Extents.Right, (float)Extents.Bottom));
            bitmapRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
            bitmapRenderTarget.Clear(new RawColor4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0f, 1.0f));

            foreach (var layer in LayerManager.Layers.Values)
            {
                if (layer.IsVisible)
                {
                    foreach (var o in layer.DrawingObjects)
                    {
                        if (o is DrawingLine drawingLine)
                        {
                            drawingLine.UpdateBrush(drawingLine.DxfLine, bitmapRenderTarget);
                            DxfHelpers.DrawLine(drawingLine, bitmapRenderTarget.Factory, bitmapRenderTarget, currentThickness);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            bitmapRenderTarget.EndDraw();
            bitmapRenderTargetNeedsUpdate = false;
            bitmapLoaded = true;
        }

I then render the bitmap to the main render target using the method below:
private void RenderBitmap(RenderTarget target)
{
    if (bitmapRenderTarget is not null)
    {
        if (bitmapRenderTargetNeedsUpdate)
        {
            LoadBitmap(target);
        }
        RawRectangleF rect = new(-200, -200, 500, 1000);
        target.DrawBitmap(bitmapRenderTarget.Bitmap, 1.0f, BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear, rect);
    }
}

My problem is that when a DXF file is loaded that ventures beyond the axes into negative coordinate space, the bitmap is cutoff at those points. My RenderBitmap method incorporates a RawRectangleF field to show this. Despite the values of -200 for left and top, the bitmap is cutoff at the x and y axes. Is there a way around this or will I just need to translate all objects on negative dxf files to positive territory? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?
I have a link here to my solution with a preloaded dxf file that shows the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-translate-an-element?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Can you clarify what you're recommending a bit? I understand how to translate an object and am already using it to pan but any translate transform I apply to the main render target doesn't help.

A bitmap only has a width and height, specifying a negative start for the source rectangle like you do is meaningless. If your rendering doesn't correspond to what you expect, it means your bitmap is incorrect (contains translated image) or your render target already defines a transform (like a translation/scale) that is incorrect, with respect to what you want
